# The mechanism of auto inserting in Pandas Dataframe when selecting rows by index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I noticed a mechanism of auto inserting when selecting rows by index. To illustrate, I use the following code:

[image]

Then my questions are 2 (may be they are the same):

1. Any document about this mechanism? (I have tried but cannot find it in the long long official documents)
2. How to avoid the auto inserting? For example, I want the last line of code returns the only 'a' row.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen any documentation. It looks like an unintended artifact. I can think of some clever things to do with it but I wouldn't trust it.

Work around

```
df1.loc[pd.Index([1, 'a']).intersection(df1.index), :]
```

Comment: Though it is a pity that the pandas fails to provide a standard way to handle it, thank you very much!